# Python Selenium Edgedriver stuck on showing "data;," in the address bar, not opening web page

Tags: python, selenium

I had this issue on 2 different systems, on first PC it went away after a reboot, on the other it had not gone away

Below is a portion of the code in question:
I masked some things on purpose

The edge browser is stuck on openign page with `data;,` shown in the address bar. It does not go beyond this.
I checked that Edge and Edgedriver are the same exact version, if it matters.
I cannot use Chrome or any other drivers for this project

Why doesn't selenium advance past the opening of the program?

I also have an error in CMD when it launches: **[9704:11992:0305/080544.278:ERROR:storage_reserve.cc(164)] Failed to open file to mark as storage reserve: C:\Users******\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir3468_1483298328\Default\Code Cache\js** on selenium

How do I fix this?

```
# importing required package of webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.opera.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

import schedule
import time
from random import randint


def job():
    while True:
        # Instantiate the webdriver with the executable location of MS Edge
        browser = webdriver.Edge(r"C:\Users\*****\Desktop\msedgedriver.exe")
        sleep(2)
        browser.maximize_window()
        sleep(2)
        browser.get('https://********/) #masked the name of website on purpose
        try:
            # Get the text box to insert Email using selector ID
            myElem_1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'anti-myhub')))
                        
            sleep(3)
            # Entering the email address
            myElem_1.click()
```